# PowerShell to pull msExchRecipientTypeDetails for Outlook 0365

Tags: powershell

I need to find a way to pull information from AD via PowerShell to tell which version of Outlook they are using. The code I currently have is very small however I made a prompt for them to enter the ADID name and then want to run the code

```
Get-ADUser USERNAME -Properties msExchRecipientTypeDetails
```

The main problem I have is I'm not sure how to take the input from the username prompt and replace it into the `Get-ADUser` command.

```
# 0365
Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the username?'
Get-ADUuser -Id USERNAME -Properties msExchRecipientTypeDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the input in a variable and use that variable with `Get-ADUser`:

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the username'
Get-ADUuser -Identity $username -Properties msExchRecipientTypeDetails
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I was way overthinking this and it now works. Thanks again.